# How to work with Express-session Cookies for authentication with front-end and back-end separated

Tags: node.js, express, session, cookies, redis

I'm trying to figure out how sessions work for authentication purposes. I have an express server running on port 5000 with redis middleware creating the cookie on every response to the backend server. I also have a React app running on port 3000 to handle the front-end. The issue is that if someone goes to "localhost:3000", the cookie won't be created because they need to go to "localhost:5000" in order for a cookie to be created.

The only solution I can think of is to use useEffect() to make a request to the server to get the cookie every time. I'm not sure if this is the proper way to do it.

Server.ts:

```
import express from "express";
import redis from "redis";
import session from "express-session";
import connectRedis from "connect-redis";
import cors from "cors";

declare module "express-session" {
  interface Session {
    username: string;
    password: string;
    email: string;
  }
}

const RedisStore = connectRedis(session);
const redisClient = redis.createClient();

redisClient.on("error", function (err) {
  console.log("Could not establish a connection with redis. " + err);
});
redisClient.on("connect", function () {
  console.log("Connected to redis successfully");
});

const app = express();

const corsOptions = {
  origin: "http://localhost:3000",
};

app.use(cors(corsOptions));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded({ extended: true }));

app.use(
  session({
    name: "joshcookie",
    store: new RedisStore({ client: redisClient, disableTouch: true }),
    cookie: { maxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, httpOnly: false, secure: false },
    secret: "jklbflasjlkdbhfoub4ou",
    saveUninitialized: true,
    resave: false,
  })
);

app.get("/", (req: express.Request, res: express.Response) => {
  const session = req.session;
  console.log(req.session.id);
  if (session.username) {
    res.send("user logged in");
  } else {
    res.send("user not logged in");
  }
});

app.post("/register", (req, res) => {
  console.log(req.body);
  req.session.username = req.body.username;
  res.end();
});

app.listen(5000, () => {
  console.log("server listening on port 5000");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's exactly what webpack devServer's [proxy](https://webpack.js.org/configuration/dev-server/#devserverproxy) is for. If you're using webpack in your React application add to the webpack config something like:

```js
  devServer: {
    proxy: {
      '/api': 'http://localhost:5000',
    },
  },
```

And while in development all your requests to `localhost:3000` will go out with `cookies` headers and will be redirected to your local node server under the hood.

Parcel has development [proxy server](https://v2.parceljs.org/features/api-proxy/) as well since the version 2.0.